# Tree Width of Directed Graph

Tags: graphs, dag, treewidth

I'm Nestor Mermoz Thea. I have two definition over the Directed strong pseudoforest and Directed weak pseudoforest that I don't really well understand.

**Directed weak pseudoforest:** A directed weak pseudoforest is a digraph, in which every weakly connected component contains at most one directed cycle.
The class of all directed weak pseudoforests is named DWPF.

**Directed strong pseudoforest**: A directed strong pseudoforest is a digraph, in which every strongly connected component contains at most one directed
cycle, i.e. contains exactly one directed cycle. The class of all directed strong pseudoforests is named DSPF

I have the following questions:

1. What ist the differences between Directed strong pseudoforest and Directed weak pseudoforest?
2. can a pseudoforest have more than one cycle?
3. what mean component in the definition.
4. can I have an Example of  Directed weak pseudoforest and Directed strong pseudoforest

Comment: A component of a forest is a tree.  Now look up what it means for a tree to be strongly connected.

Comment: I suggest you work through a few examples by hand.  Try to find an example with 2 or 3 or 4 vertices of each concept, then try to find an example of a DWPF that is not a DSPF.  I expect if you spend a little time you should be able to make some progress on that.